# Position of CSS properties order matter or not?

Tags: html, css, coding-style

This may seem like a simple question but I want to know how to position the property in the individual selectors, eg: `display` first or `width` first etc; Bellow is example, position is mixed with styling and really all over the place.

```
.box {
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    margin:25px;
    position:absolute
}
```

- Does it really matter?
- Is there any guideline we should follow?

Thanks,

Comment: Doesn't really matter - I always write properties in alphabetical order for readability though .. also vendor prefixed properties [should always appear before](http://emps.l-c-n.com/notebook/css-vendor-prefixes-and-the-cascade) the CSS property

Comment: If your adding fallbacks, it's best to put them first. As browsers will use the last rule they understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really is a matter of taste and style, for the most part. There are a number of guidelines available if you seek them out, but one place to start is Nicolas Gallagher's [Idiomatic CSS](https://github.com/necolas/idiomatic-css) – specifically the [Declaration Order](https://github.com/necolas/idiomatic-css#declaration-order) section.

> If declarations are to be consistently ordered, it should be in accordance with a single, simple principle.
>
> ...
>
> Smaller teams may prefer to cluster related properties (e.g. positioning and box-model) together.
>
> ...
>
> Larger teams may prefer the simplicity and ease-of-mainteance that comes with alphabetical ordering.

Comment: In the guide you posted. the writer suggest to use 4 spaces instead of a TAB. Isn't that though higher byte-size? I have been always using TAB.

Comment: Sure – also a highly debated matter of taste, decisions about which need to be made in light of and agreed upon by everyone working on the code. CSS formatting is for ease of reading, writing, and maintaining, and I'd recommend that you minify production CSS to eliminate unnecessary whitespace and avoid 1vs4 byte arguments altogether!

Answer (score 10):

The order of the properties does not matter (in a technical sense) unless they:

- Are the same property (including vendor prefixed versions)
- One property is a shorthand property that includes the other

For example:

```
background: url('foo');
background-color: red;
```

and

```
background-color: red;
background: url('foo');
```

… will give different results (since if you omit the `background-color` portion of the `background` property it is treated as `transparent`).

Comment: +1. The only other case I would add is for vendor prefixed properties.

Comment: @Quentin Even in the backed of the browser code, the code is executed as a block and rendering is not slowed down or anything? I know this maybe overkill but if I can find this out, It could help in the long run.